# Does permission need to have explicit package name in it?

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin

I was trying to add support for GCM in my app and have a question regarding the permissions in the Manifest (based on [this SO's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/49808507?noredirect=1)).

Is it always necessary to specify the package name in `<permission/>` tag? Or is it sufficient to have a `package` attribute just in the `<manifest>` tag?

Comment: Do not use irrelevant tags. Your question got nothing to `xml`, so I removed this tag.

Answer (score 1):

For GCM you MUST follow the pattern:

> An applicationPackage + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" permission to
>   prevent other Android applications from registering and receiving the
>   Android application's messages. The permission name must exactly match
>   this pattern—otherwise the Android application will not receive the
>   messages.

as [documented here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).

For other permissions, you may use less strict policy, but it is safer to use package name in it.

Comment: So with AndroidStudio would using `<permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />` be good enough?

Comment: You'd need also `<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE">` as documentation mentions (see link in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.YOURPERMISSION" />
```

to your manifest, you don't need to add the package name to it, if this is what you want to know.